# Checking out amazon affiliate product in my website

Tags: amazon-product-api

I have a requirement where users will visit my site and based on some logic able to earn points. The user will then be able to use this point to checkout any item of equivalent amount that is listed in my website.

The items that are to be listed is actually coming from amazon and I am an amazon affiliate so when they make the purchase i end up earning commission.

The challenges that I am facing is amazon always takes the user to their own website for the checkout, and so I am not able to put any restriction on the cost of the item that the user is checking out. The user can very well choose some other item while doing the checkout from within amazon's website.

As per my research amazon doesn't allow checkout from 3rd party websites like mine and will always bring the user to their own website. While I can create a bot using casper.js to emulate an user i dont want to go with this.

Is there any known API or solution to achieve what I am trying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have user checkout products on your website. (Why would Amazon ever allow that?)

However, I also don't think that should be important to you. You should redirect customers to Amazon with proper associate tags (`www.amazon.com/dp/...?tag=...`) in the URL. After that, any purchases that they make, irrespective of whether it was the one you showed on your website, become candidates for payouts to you. So, if you redirected a customer to product A on Amazon and she bought product B, you *might* be paid out for it, obviously if the purchase satisfied the affiliate policies.